# After applying certain condition, retain the 1st True row and all other False rows in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7, dataframe

After applying certain conditions to dataframe, below is the result of boolean expression row-wise.

```
s = pd.Series([True,False,True,False,True,False,False,False])
```

I want to retain the 1st True row and all other False rows.

**Expected output:**

Output rows of below condition:

```
output = pd.Series([True,False,False,False,False,False])
```

How to do it?

Comment: I would try and make 2 masks, 1 for true and one for false. then just keep the 1st row with true values. Speed becomes an interesting question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with:

```
s[s.cumsum().eq(1)   # first True row
  | (~s)             # or the False rows
 ]
```

Output:

```
0     True
1    False
3    False
5    False
6    False
7    False
dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 4):

#### [`Series.append`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.append.html)

```
s[s].head(1).append(s[~s])
```

---

```
0     True
1    False
3    False
5    False
6    False
7    False
dtype: bool
```